# How to set an icon for C# Windows Forms application via cmake w/o resource file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake

### Issue description

I generate the project and solution files for a Windows Forms application via `cmake`.
The resources folder of the project contains several `.ico` files, from which I want 
the select `my_icon3.ico` as icon for my application. If I open the project just after
creation by `cmake` then the `(Default Icon)` is selected as shown here:

[image: Default icon after cmake call]

What I need is a `cmake` command that directly sets the icon to `my_icon3.ico`:

[image: User selected icon]

**How can I achieve this with my `CMakeLists.txt` without a resource file?**

Thanks for your help.

### MCVE

Please find here an example to reproduce my issue:

1) Open `MS Visual Studio 15` --> New --> Project... --> Windows Forms App
2) Set name: I've chosen `P0001` and path --> Ok
3) Create folder `Resources` in the source directory and copy arbitrary icon in it.
   I've chosen `my_icon2.ico` and `my_icon3.ico`.
4) Close `MS Visual Studio 15`
5) Copy the following `CMakeLists.txt` file in the base respository:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

get_filename_component(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_COMMAND} DIRECTORY)

include(CSharpUtilities) 

#generates the directory structure given in globalDirPath.
#returns all found files (allFiles) - which need to be added to the output
function(AutoGenDirStruct globalDirPath filterF includeParentDirectory allFiles)
    if(${includeParentDirectory})
        string(FIND ${globalDirPath} "/" startPos REVERSE)
        MATH(EXPR startPos "${startPos}+1")
        string(SUBSTRING ${globalDirPath} ${startPos} 100 subDir)
        string(SUBSTRING ${globalDirPath} 0 ${startPos} globalDir)
        AutoGenDirStructInternalOnly(${globalDir} ${subDir})
    else()
        AutoGenDirStructInternalOnly(${globalDirPath} "")
    endif()

    foreach(filter ${${filterF}})
        file(GLOB_RECURSE allFilesLocal "${globalDirPath}/${filter}")
        set(mergedFiles ${mergedFiles} ${allFilesLocal})
    endforeach()
    set(${allFiles} ${mergedFiles} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()

function(AutoGenDirStructInternalOnly globalDirPath subDirectoryName)

   file(GLOB children RELATIVE "${globalDirPath}/${subDirectoryName}" "${globalDirPath}/${subDirectoryName}/*")

   foreach(child ${children})

          if(IS_DIRECTORY ${globalDirPath}/${subDirectoryName}/${child})

            AutoGenDirStructInternalOnly(${globalDirPath} ${subDirectoryName}/${child})

          else()

              if(NOT ${subDirectoryName} STREQUAL "")
                string(REPLACE "/" "\\" groupname ${subDirectoryName})
                source_group(${groupname} FILES ${globalDirPath}/${subDirectoryName}/${child})
              endif()

          endif()

   endforeach()

endfunction()

SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
SET(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:7")
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

project (P0001)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Sub-directories where more CMakeLists.txt exist
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(P0001/SRC)
```

6) Copy the following `CMakeLists.txt` file in the source directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
enable_language(CSharp)

file(GLOB SOURCES
    "*.cs"
    "*.resx"
)

SET(filter "*.cs" "*.bmp" "*.po" "*.ico" "*.config" "*.settings" "*.resx") 
AutoGenDirStruct(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} filter TRUE SOURCES)
csharp_set_designer_cs_properties(${SOURCES}) 
csharp_set_windows_forms_properties(${SOURCES})

add_executable(P0001 WIN32 ${SOURCES} ${EXTERNAL} ${RES_FILES})

set_target_properties(P0001 PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_ROOTNAMESPACE "P0001") 

set_property(TARGET P0001 PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System;System.Data;System.Configuration;System.Core;System.Data.DataSetExtensions;System.Xml;System.Xml.Linq;System.Windows.Forms;System.Drawing")
set_property(TARGET P0001 PROPERTY FOLDER "Gui")
set_property(TARGET P0001 PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.0")
```

7) Call `cmake` the generate the solution for `MS Visual Studio 15` to get [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPfv1.png)

My project repository looks as follows:

```
<Base dir>
  |--<Build>                       # folder for cmake
  |--CMakeLists.txt                # file from 5)
  |--<P0001>
  |    |--<SRC>
  |    |    |--CMakeLists.txt      # file from 6)
  |    |    |--<Resources>
  |    |    |    |--my_icon3.ico   # required icon
```

I hope that you can reproduze my issue?

### Related issues

I found some help in the net, but it's more `C++` related:

[Setting the application icon with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146172/setting-the-application-icon-with-cmake)

or it requires an `resource` file:

[[CMAKE] Setting the and Icon for a Windows Executable](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-August/031506.html)

[[SOLVED] RC files and CMake : Executable Icon problem (Visual Studio)](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/665205-solved-rc-files-and-cmake-executable-icon-problem-visual-studio/)

**Is there really no other way to configure this via `cmake`?**

Thanks again.

---

Comment: Thank you for the references, they are quite helpful for my C++ scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume:

```
set_property(TARGET P0001 PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_ApplicationIcon "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/my_icon3.ico")
```

will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, this property setting in `cmake` does the job as desired.